# how call class name from extend class

Tags: php, class

how can i call class name from extend class without implements in this class method (i want extend this function from parent class) and without call new class. If i call class name like this:

```
abstract class foo {

    public static function get_name(){
         return get_class();
         //or
         return __CLASS__;
    }
}

class bar extends foo {}

echo bar::get_name();
```

i get:

```
foo
```

expect:

```
bar
```

Comment: What do you need it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`get_called_class`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php), although it's not clear why you would want to make it a method.

Answer (score 1):

For static methods you can simply use `get_called_class()` instead of `get_class()`.

```
abstract class foo {
    public static function get_name(){
        return get_called_class();
    }
}

class bar extends foo {}
echo bar::get_name();
```